# Adding controlpoints to polyline

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, polyline

I have an existing Polyline. How I can add a control point on it? In other words I need to add a control point on the LineSegment where I click with mouse. I use WPF.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please see this link may be it help you....
[link]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357605/draw-polyline-on-picturebox

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question but I'll give a try :)
what do you mean "control point" ? 
just adding new point ?
If so, all you need is to register this method to the window "MouseDown" event :

```
  void Window1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mousePosition = (Point)e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this);
            myPolyline.Points.Add(mousePosition);
        }
```