# Draw polyline on PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, polyline

I want to draw polyline (a continuous line composed of one or more line segments) on `PictureBox`.

In this we can create multiple lines by specifying the endpoints of each segment as well as calculate distance of each segment that is distance of each line.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Nicely asked. Images are the best. People like to misunderstand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on a picturebox, the easiest thing is to inherit your own control from a `PictureBox` and provide the functionality to add endpoints when you mouse down over the picturebox.

You then store the position of the mouse click in a list, and override the `OnPaint` to draw your endpoints (ive chosen a 4x4 square) and a line between each endpoint. This is the basic code:

```
public class EndPointPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    private List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    public EndPointPictureBox()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        points.Add(new PointF(e.X,e.Y));
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        foreach(var point in points)
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,point.X-2.0f,point.Y-2.0f,4.0f,4.0f);
        if(points.Count>1)
            g.DrawLines(Pens.Black,points.ToArray());

    }
}
```

You can now add this to a Form just like a PictureBox, and choose your imagge to go inside it in the usual way.

If you try clicking a few times inside the picturebox you'll see it draws your endpoints just like your example image. Here's an example from my machine:

[image: Example endpoints]

Then your next requirement, get the distance between endpoints. This can be done by adding a class to represent an `EndPoint` with a reference to its next-door neighbour. Then its some simple Pythagorean mathematics to get the distance between the current point and the next:

```
public class EndPoint
{
    public EndPoint(int index, List<PointF> points)
    {
        this.Position = points[index];
        if (index < points.Count - 1)
            this.Next = points[index + 1];
    }
    public PointF Position { get; private set; }
    public PointF Next { get; private set; }

    public double GetDistanceToNext()
    {
        if(this.Next == PointF.Empty)
            return 0;

        var xDiff = this.Position.X - Next.X;
        var yDiff = this.Position.Y - Next.Y;

        return Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt((xDiff*xDiff) + (yDiff*yDiff)));
    }
}
```

And you can add a method to your new PictureBox to obtain this a list of these:

```
public List<EndPoint> GetEndPoints()
{
    var list = new List<EndPoint>();
    for(var i=0;i<points.Count;i++)
        list.Add(new EndPoint(i,points));
    return list;
}
```

Comment: if i want to draw that calculated distance on middle of each line segment then how could i do? like this... http://i.stack.imgur.com/nPBpx.png